# Does Moovweb support coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, mobile, coffeescript, moovweb

I've been looking into the moovweb platform lately, and I was wondering how or if Moovweb works with CoffeeScript. Can anyone provide an example of some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the moovSDK does not natively support CoffeeScript.

However, you can have a coffee folder and install the coffeescript gem. Then listen to when you change files on your coffee directory to go in to the main folder. If you do this your server should work fine on all sides.